# Add node to running cluster elasticsearch causes master not discovered exception

Tags: elasticsearch, cluster-computing, node-modules

## Problem

I have a running cluster and I would like to add a data node into it. The running cluster is

```
x.x.x.246
```

and the data node is

```
x.x.x.99
```

each server can see each other by ping.
Machine OS: CentOS7
Elasticsearch: 7.61

### configs:

here is elasticsearch.yml of x.x.x.246:

```
cluster.name: elasticsearch
node.master: true
node.name: Node_master
node.data: true
path.data: /var/lib/elasticsearch
path.logs: /var/log/elasticsearch
network.host: x.x.x.246
http.port: 9200
discovery.seed_hosts: ["x.x.x.99:9300"]
cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["x.x.x.246:9300"]
```

here is elasticsearch.yml of x.x.x.99

```
cluster.name: elasticsearch
node.name: Node_master
node.data: true
path.data: /var/lib/elasticsearch
path.logs: /var/log/elasticsearch
network.host: x.x.x.99
http.port: 9200
discovery.seed_hosts: ["x.x.x.245:9300"]
cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["x.x.x.246:9300"]
```

## Testing running elasticsearch on machine

When I run `systemctl start elasticsearch` on each machine, it works well.

### test run on x.x.x.246

```
curl -X GET "X.X.X.246:9200/_cluster/health?pretty"
```

show:number of the node not changing

```
curl -X GET "X.X.X.99:9200/_cluster/health?pretty
```

show:

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "master_not_discovered_exception",
        "reason" : null
      }
    ],
    "type" : "master_not_discovered_exception",
    "reason" : null
  },
  "status" : 503
}
```

## edited

here is elasticsearch.yml of x.x.x.246:

```
cluster.name: elasticsearch
node.name: master
node.master: true
node.data: true
path.data: /var/lib/elasticsearch
path.logs: /var/log/elasticsearch
network.host: 0.0.0.0
http.port: 9200
discovery.seed_hosts: ["x.x.x.99","x.x.x.246]
cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["x.x.x.246"]
logger.org.elasticsearch.discovery: TRACE
```

here is elasticsearch.yml of x.x.x.99

```
cluster.name: elasticsearch
node.name: node
node.data: true
path.data: /var/lib/elasticsearch
path.logs: /var/log/elasticsearch
network.host: 0.0.0.0
http.port: 9200
discovery.seed_hosts: ["x.x.x.246","x.x.x.99"]
cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["x.x.x.246"]
logger.org.elasticsearch.discovery: TRACE
```

log on x.x.x.99:

```
[root@dev ~]# tail -30 /var/log/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.log
        at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingAbstractRunnable.doRun(ThreadContext.java:692) ~[elasticsearch-7.6.1.jar:7.6.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:37) ~[elasticsearch-7.6.1.jar:7.6.1]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830) ~[?:?]
[2020-03-19T12:12:04,462][INFO ][o.e.c.c.JoinHelper       ] [node-1] failed to join {master}{0UHYehfNQ2-WCadTC_VVkA}{1FNy5AJrTpKOCAejBLKR2w}{10.64.2.246}{10.64.2.246:9300}{dilm}{ml.machine_memory=1907810304, ml.max_open_jobs=20, xpack.installed=true} with JoinRequest{sourceNode={node-1}{jb_3lJq1R5-BZtxlPs_NyQ}{a4TYDhG7SWqL3CSG4tusEg}{10.64.2.99}{10.64.2.99:9300}{d}{xpack.installed=true}, optionalJoin=Optional[Join{term=178, lastAcceptedTerm=8, lastAcceptedVersion=100, sourceNode={node-1}{jb_3lJq1R5-BZtxlPs_NyQ}{a4TYDhG7SWqL3CSG4tusEg}{10.64.2.99}{10.64.2.99:9300}{d}{xpack.installed=true}, targetNode={master}{0UHYehfNQ2-WCadTC_VVkA}{1FNy5AJrTpKOCAejBLKR2w}{10.64.2.246}{10.64.2.246:9300}{dilm}{ml.machine_memory=1907810304, ml.max_open_jobs=20, xpack.installed=true}}]}
org.elasticsearch.transport.RemoteTransportException: [master][10.64.2.246:9300][internal:cluster/coordination/join]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: failure when sending a validation request to node
        at org.elasticsearch.cluster.coordination.Coordinator$2.onFailure(Coordinator.java:514) ~[elasticsearch-7.6.1.jar:7.6.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionListenerResponseHandler.handleException(ActionListenerResponseHandler.java:59) ~[elasticsearch-7.6.1.jar:7.6.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$ContextRestoreResponseHandler.handleException(TransportService.java:1118) ~[elasticsearch-7.6.1.jar:7.6.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$ContextRestoreResponseHandler.handleException(TransportService.java:1118) ~[elasticsearch-7.6.1.jar:7.6.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.InboundHandler.lambda$handleException$2(InboundHandler.java:244) ~[elasticsearch-7.6.1.jar:7.6.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingRunnable.run(ThreadContext.java:633) ~[elasticsearch-7.6.1.jar:7.6.1]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830) [?:?]
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.transport.RemoteTransportException: [node-1][10.64.2.99:9300][internal:cluster/coordination/join/validate]
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.cluster.coordination.CoordinationStateRejectedException: join validation on cluster state with a different cluster uuid P4QlwvuRRGSmlT77RroSjA than local cluster uuid oUoIe2-bSbS2UPg722ud9Q, rejecting
        at org.elasticsearch.cluster.coordination.JoinHelper.lambda$new$4(JoinHelper.java:148) ~[elasticsearch-7.6.1.jar:7.6.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.transport.SecurityServerTransportInterceptor$ProfileSecuredRequestHandler$1.doRun(SecurityServerTransportInterceptor.java:257) ~[?:?]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:37) ~[elasticsearch-7.6.1.jar:7.6.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.transport.SecurityServerTransportInterceptor$ProfileSecuredRequestHandler.messageReceived(SecurityServerTransportInterceptor.java:315) ~[?:?]
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.RequestHandlerRegistry.processMessageReceived(RequestHandlerRegistry.java:63) ~[elasticsearch-7.6.1.jar:7.6.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.InboundHandler$RequestHandler.doRun(InboundHandler.java:264) ~[elasticsearch-7.6.1.jar:7.6.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingAbstractRunnable.doRun(ThreadContext.java:692) ~[elasticsearch-7.6.1.jar:7.6.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:37) ~[elasticsearch-7.6.1.jar:7.6.1]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830) ~[?:?]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For node `x.x.x.99` the entry for seed host is wrong. It should be as below:

```
discovery.seed_hosts: ["x.x.x.246:9300"]
```

The `discovery.seed_hosts` list is used to detect the master node, since this list contains the address to the nodes which are master eligible nodes and hold the information of the current master node as well, Since it is pointed to `x.x.x.245` instead of `x.x.x.246` in the configuration of `x.x.x.99`, the node `x.x.x.99` is unable to detect the master.

**Post discussion in comment** correct configuration should be:

**Master node:**

```
cluster.name: elasticsearch
node.name: master
node.master: true
node.data: true
path.data: /var/lib/elasticsearch
path.logs: /var/log/elasticsearch
network.host: 0.0.0.0
http.port: 9200
discovery.seed_hosts: ["x.x.x.246]
cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["master"]
```

Note that if you want the above node to be master only and not hold data then set

```
node.data: false
```

**Data node:**

```
cluster.name: elasticsearch
node.name: data-node-1
node.data: true
node.master: false
path.data: /var/lib/elasticsearch
path.logs: /var/log/elasticsearch
network.host: 0.0.0.0
http.port: 9200
discovery.seed_hosts: ["x.x.x.246"]
```

Also since node `x.x.x.99` could not join cluster it has stale cluster state. So delete `data` folder on `x.x.x.99` and restart this node.

Comment: hi there thank you for your response but it was my typo here, in the yml file it was written 246

Comment: @yuliansen Is node x.x.x.99 a new node and you want it to be data only node?

Comment: Yes sir. The point is to expand the capacity of running the running cluster.

Comment: Few more clarifications required: 1) x.x.x.246 was part of the already running cluster? 2) x.x.x.99 will not be a master eligible node?

Comment: yes sir. The point is to expand the capacity of running cluster (x.x.x.246)

Comment: @yuliansen Updated my answer

Comment: hi there, im sorry im new in this. How do we delete data on elasticsearch. I want to delete data on x.x.x.99

Comment: As defined in yml you have configure your data directory as `/var/lib/elasticsearch`. You can empty this directory.

Comment: alright, i've headed into that location and rm -rf nodes. and restarted the service. nothing changes. it still returning the same exception. i will take a look at log.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209911/discussion-between-opster-es-ninja-nishant-and-yuliansen).

Comment: Im sorry i just take a look into, the log and it written seems im being desperate so i didnt change the discovery seeds. After i change it, now it working. The nodes increasing into 2. Thank you so much.

Comment: Im sorry i just take a look into, the log and it written seems im being desperate so i didnt change the discovery seeds. After i change it, now it working. The nodes increasing into 2. Thank you so much.

Comment: Glad it worked. Please accept the answer as well :)

Comment: Removing data from nodes folder from /var/lib/elasticsearch/nodes on ubuntu helped a lot. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 3):

I had also same issue, when I was trying to access elastic search from outside AWS windows server, I was not able to access it, after that I have added

```
network.host : aws_private_ip
```

and after that we need to restart elastic service, but it was throwing an error in restarting, and finally when had added below line, it works for me,

```
cluster.initial_master_nodes: node-1
```

Comment: Posts on Stack Overflow shouldn't contain a "signature" within the question or answer. There's a user-card below every post, which serves the purpose of a signature. If a visitor wants to know more about you, they can either hover the mouse over your user-card and see the first part of your profile text, or click through to your profile page and see much more information, including whatever you've written in your profile "about me" section. If you do include an additional signature in your posts, many people tend to react to such signatures as if they were spam (i.e. negatively).

Answer (score 2):

The reason, why it wasn't able to elect a master, is mention of `discovery.seed_hosts: ["x.x.x.245:9300"]` which is not part of the current master node config and is not part of master node config as well. as mentioned in [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/discovery-settings.html) official ES docs it's used to elect a master node.

You should read in details the 2 important configs related to master selection:

[discovery.seed_hosts](http://discovery.seed_hosts)

[initial_master_nodes](http://initial_master_nodes)

You can turn DEBUG logging on `Discovery` module to better understand it, by adding below the line in your `elasticsearch.yml`

```
logger.org.elasticsearch.discovery: DEBUG
```

**You can do a few modifications in both the `elasticsearch.yml`.**

1. `node.name` has same name in both nodes `elasticsearch.yml`.
2. It's better to just mention ip without port `9200`.
3. Better to give `network.host: 0.0.0.0` value, instead of node ip in both `elasticsearch.yml`.
4. `node.data: true` is the default, so no need to mention it.

So better and concise version looks like below:

### Master node elasticsearch.yml

```
cluster.name: elasticsearch
node.name: master
path.data: /var/lib/elasticsearch
path.logs: /var/log/elasticsearch
network.host: 0.0.0.0
discovery.seed_hosts: ["x.x.x.99", "x.x.x.246"] -->note this
cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["x.x.x.246"] :- note this
```

### Another data node elasticsearch.yml

```
cluster.name: elasticsearch
node.name: data
path.data: /var/lib/elasticsearch
path.logs: /var/log/elasticsearch
network.host: 0.0.0.0
http.port: 9200
discovery.seed_hosts: ["x.x.x.99", "x.x.x.246"] --> you need to change this and include both nodes
cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["x.x.x.246"]
```

### Verify the master node

You can hit `<your-any-node-ip>:9200/_cat/master` and this should return the elected master node which would be in your case node with name `master`. more info on [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cat-master.html).

Comment: hi there, thank you for your response, i've updated my yml file but nothing changes, x.x.x.99 still have master_not_discover_exception. Error log will be updated on main thread. Please help me check it out and give me more insight. Thank you so much.

Comment: @yuliansen, did you try to start both your `master` and `data` node at the same time? can you mark `node.master: false` in your data node `elasticsearch.yml` and start again only data node

Comment: @yuliansen, did you get a chance to look at my suggestions

Comment: hi, i've tried to start x.x.x.246 node.master:false and when i run it, it also returning master_not_discovered_exception. I've run both of them and they show the same exception.

Comment: @yuliansen, you mentioned ` x.x.x.246 ` is your master node, you need to revert this and add `node.master: false` in your data node config and restart first master and then restart data node

Comment: yes i've done it. I've changed elasticsearch.yml node.master: false and run it. elasticsearch.service run. but when i curl http://x.x.x.246:9200/_cluster/health?pretty it show master_master_not_discovered_exception. The same thing also happened to x.x.x.99 when i run them together.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209905/discussion-between-opster-elasticsearch-ninja-and-yuliansen).